How to call a function from class where instance of another class
I'd like to ask you if there is another way to call function from a class where this INSTANCE of another class is coming from?
Or do you think my approach is correct?
class App(){
  constructor(){
    this.interface = new Interface();
  }

  refresh(){
  ...refresh app somehow...   
  }
}

class Interface(){
  constructor(){}

  changeInterface(){
    ...change interface somehow...
    this.App.Refresh(); // => I need to call this function from previous class
  }
}

var myGlobalVariable = new App();
    myGlobalVariable.interface.changeInterface();

Only I can think of is to use global variable inside...but than I need to set this variable and use it all the time
var myGlobalVariable = new App();
    myGlobalVariable.interface.changeInterface();

and use it in a Class
class Interface(){
  constructor(){}

  changeInterface(){
    ...change interface...
    myGlobalVariable.App.Refresh(); // => call function from pre set
  }
}

Or maybe my thinking is wrong and I have to change it?
Thanks.

If Interface instances need to interact with an instance of App, then pass an instance of App to the instance of Interface. Either in the constructor or the method, or whatever makes sense. Right now, there isn't really enough code to figure out why that isn't the first thing you did.

You should ask yourself if it's really the responsability of the interface to refresh the app. It looks more like the responsability of the app itself. Maybe you could create a function in the app class that call the changeInterface and then call the refresh function on itself.

OK, I misread the code. There is already a link from App to Interface. Why not do a double link? this.interface = new Interface(this); in App, then Interface can use App. Although, the strucure is weird. Seems to imply you somehow access to Interface instance but not access to App? Why would you consider global variables otherwise? If you do have access to App, then just refresh it. Why should an inner component be 1. exposed to the outside 2. responsible to do something with its parent? There is at the very least tight coupling.

@Nicolas yes I tried this also and it was working however I'd like to put it inside the Interface Class because this class is responsible for all interface changes and calculations.  So I wanted to have functions together. Maybe I stay with this solution. Thanks.

There has to be a duplicate of this, it's a very common problem with a standard solution.

as VLAZ mentioned I had to create another link with "this" and then use it in constructor so...
class App(){
  constructor(){
    this.interface = new Interface(this); // using this inside of new instance
  }

  refresh(){
  ...refresh app somehow...   
  }
}

class Interface(){
  constructor(thisValue){
    this.App = thisValue; // pas "thisValue" to local variable
  }

  changeInterface(){
    ...change interface somehow...
    this.App.Refresh(); // => calling this function from previous class using this.App variable in constructor
  }
}

BIG BIG thanks @VLAZ!
